# PHP Password Protect form needs password entered twice before working

Tags: php, setcookie, crypt

I'm trying to make a password protected website. The password is currently just hardcoded to make it easier for me to test.

The problem that I'm running into is that when I type the actual password, the cookie doesn't seem to get set. If I re-enter the password a second time, then the cookie gets set.

I know that the problem is the order that I am calling the code, but I'm having a hard time actually identifying what I should change in order to make it function correctly on the first correct password input. Any help would be appreciated.

```
     case 'Maintenance':

$salt = "test";
$adminpass = "adminpass";
$RealPassword = crypt($adminpass, $salt);

function LoginScreen($SaltCode){
?>

    <html>
<head>
  <title>Please enter password to access this page</title>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    input { border: 1px solid black; }
  </style>
  <div style="width:500px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center">
  <form method="post">
    <h3>Please enter password to access this page</h3>
    <font color="red"><?php echo $error_msg; ?></font><br />
    <input type="password" name="access_password" /><p></p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <br />
  </div>
</body>
</html> 






<?php
global $PasswordEntered;
$PasswordEntered = crypt($_POST['access_password'],$SaltCode);

}









if (!isset($_COOKIE["Cookie"]))
{ 

LoginScreen($salt);

if ($PasswordEntered == $RealPassword)
    {
        setcookie("Cookie", $PasswordEntered, time()+600);
    } 

}



if (isset($_COOKIE["Cookie"]))
{

?>  

<B><fontsize=16>Are you sure you want to Format the data disk?</b></font><br><br>


<form method = "post">

<INPUT TYPE = 'Submit' name = 'FormatSubmit' value = 'Submit'>


<br><br><br>
Please check the box to verify you want to Format the data disk.

<Input type = "Checkbox" Name ="FormatCheck" value ="checked">


</form>

<?php
if (($_POST['FormatSubmit'] == "Submit") & ($_POST['FormatCheck'] == "checked"))
    {
    html_exec_cmd('echo -e "o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw\n" | fdisk /dev/sda;sleep 1;mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda1;mount /dev/sda1 /data/');
     }

}

     break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up completely dropping the setcookie parameter, because I couldn't figure out a way to resolve it. I decided to go with the $_SESSION parameter to get it to work. An added bonus is that the session is controlled serverside, so the security will be higher.

```
case 'Login':

      $salt = "test";
      $adminpass = "adminpass";
      $RealPassword = crypt($adminpass, $salt);

      if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
        echo "You are already logged in.";
      }
      else if ($_POST['access_password']){
        $PasswordEntered = crypt($_POST['access_password'],$salt);
        if ($PasswordEntered == $RealPassword){
            $_SESSION['loggedin']=1;
            LogData('Logged in',$logdir);
            echo "You are now logged in!";
        }
        else{
            echo LoginScreen();
            LogData('Failed login attempt',$logdir);
        }
      }
      else{ 
        echo LoginScreen();
      }
    break;
```

Comment: Should be noted that $_SESSION is not a server side cookie (thus destroying the definition of what a cookie is), it is a PHP session.

Comment: Nice catch, I must have typed that by accident.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is only sent as part of a request:

```
setcookie("Cookie", $PasswordEntered, time()+600);

if (isset($_COOKIE["Cookie"])) {
}
```

This will fail if it is in the same request.

You could however do the following:

```
setcookie("Cookie", $PasswordEntered, time()+600);
// might be consudered bad practice though to directly edit the superglobal, so be wary of WTF's
$_COOKIE["Cookie"] = $PasswordEntered;

if (isset($_COOKIE["Cookie"])) {
}
```

BTW, what is this: `global $PasswordEntered;`??

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, what would be a good way to fix this?


I used the global as a way to call the variable outside the function.

Comment: @pr- updated my answer. About the global: it isn't even inside a function?

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing something. The global is in the function LoginScreen. I understand my code is probably confusing and probably in bad practice, because I used the global $PasswordEntered as the cookie data. This is just the first time I've actually written my own code for setcookie and crypt.

Comment: I wait now I see it. You should drop that `global` and add the `$PasswordEntered;` as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with another variable, like this:

```
<?php

global $PasswordEntered;
if (isset($_POST['access_password'])){
    $PasswordEntered = crypt($_POST['access_password'],$SaltCode);
} else {
    $PasswordEntered='';
}
}
$pass=false;
if (!isset($_COOKIE["Cookie"]))
{ 
    LoginScreen($salt);

if ($PasswordEntered == $RealPassword)
{
    setcookie("Cookie", $PasswordEntered, time()+600);
    $pass=true;
} 
}

if (isset($_COOKIE["Cookie"]) || $pass)
{
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: This sort of works. It allows me to at least "login", but the problem that I run into is that the login screen is still displayed above the actual content. Typing in my password again and hitting login, makes it completely disappear.